# Openssl Relocation error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt some files using openssl , it showing me following error

> openssl: relocation error: openssl: symbol EVP_mdc2 version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference

Do I have to reinstall it ? or some dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDC-2)

> Because of patent concerns support for MDC-2 has been disabled in OpenSSL on most Linux distributions and is not implemented by many other cryptographic libraries.

The algorithm itself is available in OpenSSL, but it is not compiled in. If you really want to use it, download the source package, modify the `debian/rules` file so that this line:

```
CONFARGS  = --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)\
no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 no-zlib no-ssl3 enable-unit-test no-ssl3-method enable-rfc3779\
enable-cms
```

does not include `no-mdc2` and compile it (it might be as simple as `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`).

Otherwise use **aes-256** with something like **sha256**.